# How many carbs I will lose by cold fermenting my bread dough?

Tags: baking, bread, low-carb

I made bread dough recently, and I want to know how many carbs I'll lose using the specific method below:

1. Composition: 6.5 cups of whole wheat flour (21g of carbs per 1/4 cup, per the nutrition facts), 1.5 tsp salt, two packets of yeast (1.5 TBS).
2. Left it to rise overnight
3. Put it in Ziploc bags in refrigerator to let the yeast have at the carbs.

I am going to bake some at 3, 5 and 7 days for comparison, so I would love to have data for that, too.

Answer (score 9):

Though it's true that yeast will consume some of the carbs to produce byproducts (such as CO2) that affect the flavor and texture of the bread, the amount that these microorganisms will consume is tiny compared to the amount of carbs that exist in the bread.

It won't be a noticeable amount from a human nutrition perspective.